# SQL Injection in sql match query

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-injection

Is this query hackable using sql injection ?

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable_fts where mytable_fts match ?
```

example

SELECT count(*) FROM mytable_fts where mytable_fts match "a"

I tried using

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable_fts where mytable_fts match "a" OR 1==1
```

but it didn't worked as it is going as match parameter.

can any body give example of sql injection on this query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL injection vulnerability has less to do with the query itself, than with how the query is constructed.  If you use query variables instead of string concatenation, you will be OK.  If you use string concatenation, then any query with parameters is vulnerable.

Comment: I am using prepared statement provided by sqlite.